# Как присвоить props в state в React

Tags: reactjs

Есть родительский компонент List.js в котором на хуке componentDidMount я получаю категории которые буду использовать в этом компонете и которые хочу использовать в дочернем AddPostForm.js. В компоненте AddPostForm у меня в стейте есть title, body - это два inputs а category относиться к select тегу и когда в этом селекте выбераеться option то он присваиваеться к category. Проблема что при инициализации компонента AddPostForm мне нужно установить дефолтное значение в категории (взять первый элемент с this.props.categories[0].name). Как это можно сделать правильно?

AddPostForm.js

```
import React from 'react';
import postApi from '../../services/postApi';

class AddPostForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: '',
            body: '',
            category: ''
        };
    }

    handleInputChange = event => {
        const name = event.target.name;
        const value = event.target.value;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    };

    formSubmit = async event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { status, data } = await postApi.addPost({
            title: this.state.title,
            body: this.state.body,
            category: this.state.category,
        });

        if (status === 200) {
            this.setState({
                title: '',
                body: '',
                category: this.props.categories[0].name
            });

            this.props.addPost(data);
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.formSubmit} className="mb-3">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="title" className="form-control" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <textarea name="body" className="form-control" value={this.state.body} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <select className="form-control" name="category" value={this.state.category} onChange={this.handleInputChange}>
                        {this.props.categories.map(item => (
                            <option key={item._id}>{item.name}</option>
                        ))}
                    </select>
                </div>
                <button className="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default AddPostForm;
```

List.js

```
import React from 'react';
import categoryApi from '../../services/categoryApi';
import AddPostForm from './AddPostForm';

class List extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            posts: [],
            categories: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        categoryApi.getCategories().then(response => {
            if (response.data.length) {
                this.setState({
                    categories: response.data
                });
            }
        });
    }

    addPost = async post => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            posts: [...prevState.posts, post],
        }));
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="shadow p-3 mt-4">
                <AddPostForm categories={this.state.categories} addPost={this.addPost} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default List;
```

Comment: Пока нет данных не рисовать форму, а лоадер какой-то

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подсказали вот такое решение моей проблемы
AddPostForm.js

```
import React from 'react';
import postApi from '../../services/postApi';

class AddPostForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: '',
            body: '',
            category: ''
        };
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (prevState.category === '' && this.props.categories.length > 0) {
            this.setState({ category: this.props.categories[0].name });
        }
    }

    handleInputChange = event => {
        const name = event.target.name;
        const value = event.target.value;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    };

    formSubmit = async event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { status, data } = await postApi.addPost({
            title: this.state.title,
            body: this.state.body,
            category: this.state.category
        });

        if (status === 200) {
            this.setState({
                title: '',
                body: '',
                category: this.props.categories[0].name
            });

            this.props.addPost(data);
        }
    };

    render() {
        const select =
            this.props.categories.length === 0 ? null : (
                <select className="form-control" name="category" value={this.props.categories[0].name} onChange={this.handleInputChange}>
                    {this.props.categories.map(item => (
                        <option key={item._id}>{item.name}</option>
                    ))}
                </select>
            );

        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.formSubmit} className="mb-3">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="title" className="form-control" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <textarea name="body" className="form-control" value={this.state.body} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">{select}</div>
                <button className="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default AddPostForm;
```

Answer (score 1):

Во первых `componentDidMount` не хук а жизненный цикл

Во вторых для того чтобы инициализировать дефолтное значение не надо писать вот так `this.props.categories[0].name` или что то подобное.

В реакте есть свойство **defaultProps** которое позволяет установить пропсы по умолчанию.

```
static defaultProps = {
    name: "Тест",
};
```

Если пропсов нет то по умолчанию данные берутся из `defaultProps`.

[**Документация**](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops) React

Пример `defaultProps` на классовых и функциональных компонентах [**тут**](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-snow-tfunp)